# Jquery Success method not works when we send data cross domain using post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, cross-domain

I am trying to login using cross domain **jQuery** ajax request. After complete request my success method not work.

```
jQuery("#loginButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        url: "http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=login",
        data: {
            log: jQuery("#username").val(), pwd: jQuery("#password").val(),remember: false, },
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you see in the browser's console?

Comment: I am getting response in console log but in succees function alert or any response not display.

Comment: and i have also set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my php code

Comment: Getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked:The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing